# Error in function deployment in gcloud. Resource readiness deadline exceeded

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a Cloud Function, using eventarc and a pub/sub topic as a trigger. The function's source code comes from a .zip file, which is 11MB. I define everything according to the documentation, I was allocating 2GB of RAM and 1 CPU for the function. However, it is returning me the termination of the following error "The server has encountered an internal error. Please try again later. Resource readiness deadline exceeded.", I looked for ways to solve it, I thought it could be permissions, but even being the owner of the project was not working out. Apparently it's giving an error when creating the container in Cloud Run, I looked in the Artifact Registry and the container was 0.4GB. Then I believe that there may be some limitation regarding the size of the function that I want to raise.

I tried to change some things in the code, like specifying versions in the requirements (I'm using python 3.8), putting prints to see where it could be giving an error, I made changes to the functions to see if it would work, I tried to create in different accounts and still without success.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.